# Oracle VARCHAR2 - Inserted value too large for column

Tags: java, oracle, varchar2

Working on a Java/Spring system with Oracle(19c Enterprise) database, I have recently bumped into this error:

```
database.org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; 
uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{? = call booking_system_pkg.create_booking(?, ?, ?)}]; 
SQL state [99999]; error code [17072]; 
Inserted value too large for column: "E2BF85FFF1DFAB55E05329CC1C0A850E"; 
nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Inserted value too large for column: 
"E2BF85FFF1DFAB55E05329CC1C0A850E"
```

I have checked that the data type of that column is `varchar2(60)`. Since the value "E2BF85FFF1DFAB55E05329CC1C0A850E" is all ASCII characters, `varchar2(60)` should be enough to hold this value, isn't it?

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you add the database NLS parameters output to your question?
select
  parameter,
  value
from
  v$nls_parameters;

Comment: Are you looking for the charset params? If so: (NLS_CHARACTERSET: AL32UTF8), (NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET: AL16UTF16)

Comment: There is some information hidden somewhere. I would have expected ORA-12899. You need to have a look at errors raised by the pkg.
insert into t values ('E2BF85FFF1DFAB55E05329CC1C0A850E');
insert into t values ('E2BF85FFF1DFAB55E05329CC1C0A850E')
                      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-12899: value too large for column "ADMIN"."T"."X" (actual: 32, maximum: 1)

Answer (score 1):

E2BF85FFF1DFAB55E05329CC1C0A850E is 32 characters long. Despite being all ASCII, your database will encode it using whatever encoding it is set to use. It will not mix and match encoding depending on the specific string being inserted into a column, think of how expensive and confusing searching and sorting on a table with multiple encodings would get.

If the column is indeed a varchar2(60) and "E2BF85FFF1DFAB55E05329CC1C0A850E" is too large for the column, then the logical conclusion is that the column is set to 60 bytes, not characters, and your database is using a multi-byte encoding.